# Why does an equality check in Ruby behave this way with an OR expression?

Tags: ruby, syntax, logic

I came across something like this in some specs at work today. A service was checking if a param was either `"true"` as a String or `true` as a TrueClass. It looked legit to me, but I found that it only evaluated to true when the supplied param value was the same as the first element in the OR.

A simplified example below:

`5 == (5 || 6)` evaluates to `true`

`5 == (6 || 5)` evaluates to `false`

Why?

Comment: This is known as "short circuiting". `5 || 6` is the same as `if 5 then 5 else 6 end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `(6 || 5)` returns 6 (`||` returns the first true condition), not 5:

```
[2] pry(main)> (6 || 5)
# => 6
```

So `5 == (6 || 5)` is just the same as `5 == 6` which is, of course, false.

Comment: Thank you, I feel silly now. I would have caught this had I been writing the code myself, but I found it already there, assumed it worked and read intent rather than actual execution. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Everything is truthy in Ruby, except `nil` and `false`. So as others have mentioned, `5 || 6` is just 5.

I suppose that with :

```
5 == (6 || 5)
# => false
```

you actually meant to write

```
[5, 6].include? 5
# => true
```

Comment: Thanks! I see it now. Silly mistake. Cheers!